# Stored procedure with parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have to pass a parameter to stored procedure in SQL Server.  Parameter value is to be used as comma separated list in the "IN" clause:

So something like this:

```
... ... 
@myParam as varChar(max)
.... .. 

select *
from myTable 
where someValue in (@myParam).
```

So, I think, I have to somehow pass in the parameter that is a sql string itself.  Stored procedure is called from Java with Hibernate call.

Any advise is appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(5000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
            FROM myTable
            WHERE somevalue IN ('+ @myParam+')'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was thinking as well, however I need the select * from my table ... actually be 'select * INTO #TEMP'... Your advice works perfectly without the "into" part.  If I put "into #temp" the #temp is not accessible after exec

Comment: My stored procedure is large, and have to use the previous results at every step.

Comment: Try using global temp tables like ##temp. Don't forget to delete them at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to convert comma separated value to table and then you can use table to do a SELECT within an IN CLAUSE or you can also do a JOIN if you want. This way you can use it for any datatype i.e. Comma separated varchar or int value. (You will just have to make the function generic)

See below URL:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function or cte to extract the data and then use a Join or a Where in (select ....)
Notice the current algorithm needs a delimiter at the end.
If you use a UDF you could pass @separator and @source as parameters

```
DECLARE @separator  varchar(1024) = ','
DECLARE @source varchar(1024) = 'valueA,ValueB,ValueC,'

;WITH cteDelimitedExtractor (item, delimitedString) AS
(
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(@source, 1, CHARINDEX(@separator, @source ) - 1)  AS ititem,
        SUBSTRING(@source, CHARINDEX(@separator, @source ) + 1, LEN(@source) - CHARINDEX(@separator, @source))  as delimitedString
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(delimitedString, 1, CHARINDEX(@separator, delimitedString ) - 1)  AS item,
        SUBSTRING(delimitedString, CHARINDEX(@separator, delimitedString ) + 1, LEN(delimitedString) - CHARINDEX(@separator, delimitedString ))  as delimitedString
    FROM cteDelimitedExtractor
    WHERE delimitedString <> ''
)
SELECT item FROM cteDelimitedExtractor
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for a short input. But for a larger lenth of input, I am getting an error "Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_myStoredProc, Line 17
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function" :(

Comment: Have you put a delimiter at the end?. How many items has your input?

Comment: Thanks so much. That was a delimeter issue.  The short list (below 10 items) by putting it there, just for test.  My actual list is somewhat larger.  I don't know yet, I am optimizing application running time, so am designing a solution for a more optimal selection of data - will try between 100 and 500 items. There are about 20000 records to choose from, and when I do item-by-item I get out of memory. After a many hours of work the dataset returned is somewhat 1-2 millions of records of about 10 columns each. Have to do with the IN clause.  Thanks for the pointers again.

Comment: Figured out that this way it works only for 113 items in a list.  If I put more, I get that error " Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function" "..

Comment: I think it could be due to a missing delimiter at the end of the string. Could you check if your delimited string has the final delimiter.

Comment: Another thing to take into account with this implementation, you could have to use "option (maxrecursion XXXX)". To operate with a very big list of items but I think it is not the issue you had. The error in that case should be "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion XXXX has been exhausted before statement completion." By default SQL Server uses 100 recursion depth.

Comment: It you string has the final delimiter, please do a "SELECT len(@delimitedstring), right(@delimitedstring, 1)" by using the bigger string that works and another one that doesnt work.

Comment: Santiago, thanks.  Our DBA in a "friendly" manner strongly urged NOT to pass in the string of comma-separated values.  I went with another way - I run a small stored procedure first, that takes a list of ALL of the ids I need, places them into stationary temp table.  Then in the stored Procedure that is in question here, I take top 1000 from that and put into a #temp table, this way I run the 2nd stored procedure N/1000+1 number of times called form Java loop.  This take a little time, but it is of no issue to us. No memory leaks and results match to what is expected. Everyone is happy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the string value from wherever you are calling the procedure.